# Error in apk uploaded to Google Play

Tags: android, android-fragments, apk

i have created an application to promote a restaurante, have swipe view and list view and a map, but went close the application he crashed, someone send me the error to the developer console:

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to destroy activity {com.sapires.Pizza/com.sapires.Joes.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3517)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3535)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:145)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1259)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5144)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:611)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss(FragmentManager.java:1360)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1378)
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:595)
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:574)
at com.sapires.Joes.Mapa.onDestroyView(Mapa.java:70)
at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performDestroyView(Fragment.java:1709)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1011)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1121)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1103)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchDestroy(FragmentManager.java:1938)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onDestroy(FragmentActivity.java:336)
at android.app.Activity.performDestroy(Activity.java:5403)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnDestroy(Instrumentation.java:1117)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3504)
```

and went i go to the map and go again to another screen and rotate the screen even crashes with this error:

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to destroy activity {com.sapires.Pizza/com.sapires.Joes.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3795)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3813)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4013)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:173)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1309)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5579)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss(FragmentManager.java:1360)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1378)
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:595)
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:574)
at com.sapires.Joes.Mapa.onDestroyView(Mapa.java:70)
at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performDestroyView(Fragment.java:1709)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1011)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1121)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1103)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchDestroy(FragmentManager.java:1938)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onDestroy(FragmentActivity.java:336)
at android.app.Activity.performDestroy(Activity.java:5623)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnDestroy(Instrumentation.java:1123)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3782)
```

I use fragmentes. Someone can explain me what happens?

Answer (score 0):

```
try following on back press of map to another screen and use saveinstant state for rotation of screen

 @Override
        public void onDestroyView() {
            super.onDestroyView();
            MapFragment f = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
                                                 .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
            if (f != null) 
                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(f).commit();
        }
```

Comment: return a error: Cannot cast from Fragment to MapFragment

Answer (score 0):

This is the map java

```
    package com.sapires.Joes;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.sapires.Pizza.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class Mapa extends Fragment {

    private static final double MARKER_LATITUDE = 42.027325;
    private static final double MARKER_LONGITUDE = -8.640842;
    GoogleMap map;
    private FragmentActivity myContext;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View android = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mapa_3, container, false);
        final LatLng position = new LatLng(MARKER_LATITUDE, MARKER_LONGITUDE);

        // marker
        FragmentManager fragManager = myContext.getSupportFragmentManager();
        map =  ((SupportMapFragment) fragManager.findFragmentById(R.id.mapFragment1)).getMap();
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(position)
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.pizzaria))
            .title("Pizzaria Joes\n251 824 818"));

        // camera position
        map.setOnCameraChangeListener(new OnCameraChangeListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition arg0)
            {
                CameraUpdate cu = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(position, 17);
                map.animateCamera(cu);
                map.setOnCameraChangeListener(null);
                map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
            }
        });
        return android;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        myContext=(FragmentActivity) activity;
        super.onAttach(activity);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        Fragment f = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapFragment1);
        if (f != null)
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(f).commit();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
package com.sunil.assignment;

    import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.UiSettings;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptor;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
    import com.sunil.assignment.R.drawable;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.app.Fragment;
    import android.app.FragmentManager;
    import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
    import android.graphics.Bitmap;
    import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
    import android.graphics.BitmapFactory.Options;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class First extends Fragment{
        FragmentManager man;

        private GoogleMap googleMap;
        MapFragment mMapFragment;
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.firstscreen, container, false);


             try {
                    // Loading map
                    initilizeMap();

                } catch (Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();


                }



                LatLng mumbai=new LatLng(18.9300, 72.8200);
             googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);

             googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(mumbai, 13));

               // googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().title("Mumbai").snippet("Dream City").position(mumbai));
             // latitude and longitude
                double latitude = 18.9300;
                double longitude = 72.8200;

                // create marker
                final MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title("Hello");




                // adding marker
                googleMap.addMarker(marker);

               googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                     Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Churchgate", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    googleMap.addMarker( marker.
                            icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.images)).title("Mumbai").snippet("Dream City").
                        position(new LatLng(18.9300,72.8200)));

                      return true;
                }
                    });  

                return v;
        }

            /**
             * function to load map. If map is not created it will create it for you
             * */
            private void initilizeMap() {
               /*
                 mMapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

                 if (mMapFragment == null) {
                       FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                       FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                       mMapFragment = MapFragment.newInstance();
                       fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.map, mMapFragment).commit();

                       Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                         }

                 if (mMapFragment != null)
                 {
                     googleMap = mMapFragment.getMap();

                     Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "hi", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                     if (googleMap != null)
                            googleMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap. OnMapClickListener()
                            {
                             @Override
                             public void onMapClick(LatLng point)
                             {
                              //TODO: your onclick stuffs
                                 Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "hi", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                             }
                            });
                 }   */

                if (googleMap == null) {



                    googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                            R.id.map)).getMap();   

                    // check if map is created successfully or not
                    if (googleMap == null) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                                "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                .show();
                    }
                }   
            }

            @Override
            public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onAttach(activity);
            }
            @Override
            public void onDestroyView() {
                super.onDestroyView();
                MapFragment f = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
                                                     .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
                if (f != null) 
                    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(f).commit();
            }


        }
```

Comment: this is your code, i can adapt to me, i allready have the onDetroy:  @Override
 public void onDestroyView() {
  super.onDestroyView();
  Fragment f = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapFragment1);
  
   getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(f).commit();
 }

Comment: mapa is fragment and your replacing it over activity so use addbackstack to null